# Removing small annotations from image

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I am trying to remove small images from graphs using Python.  As an example, I attach a graph with some '+' and '-' annotating it.  I don't want them there, but don't want to manually remove them as there are quite a few to go through.  Any easy way to detect and remove them?

[image: Graph with annotations]

Comment: yes there are ways
First you read [ask] and apply what you learn.

Comment: Do you think this has been answered before?  I couldn't find anything.  Or is the problem in the question?  Seems clear to me, even if I haven't included any code.

Comment: Well I'll quote a few Stackoverflow guidelines: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. ---- 
...... Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Show some ideas. Tell me what you know about image processing so I don't have to write 10 pages.
How would you start?

Comment: Well it's not homework, I'm just writing a very crude script to extract the data from the graphs to digitise the data for use in a colleague's research, and the annotations are screwing it up.  I know very little (/nothing) about image processing and at the moment don't have time to learn a whole new field just to save him a couple of hours in paint.  I've gone through examples on scikit-image and opencv website, but nothing I found seemed applicable. I assume it is easy to do, and mostly just wanted a suggestion of what the correct algorithm/technique to Google would be.

Comment: just forget about the homework part. It's just that you are expected to do something yourself on this platform. If you just want a quick tip try to find blobs and delete everthing that does not belong to your "graph" blob which will be most likely the biggest blob in the image. simple and stupid but it should fine. If you don't have time to learn image processing pay someone who can do what you want.

Comment: @Piglet: There are small breaks in the graph, so I'd assume that blob analyis alone might be not sufficient, I have added a little morphology. I agree in principle with the "show some ideas" part, but I really had it almost ready sitting on my desk, no insult intended.

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you a solution using blob analysis since I had it almost ready at hand, but would ask you to do the reading and explanation yourself, since you have not spent too much time on your own code. Maybe it helps anyway.

Resulting image:

[image: Resulting image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

imgray = cv2.imread('image.png')


#### Blob analysis
# SimpleBlobDetector will find black blobs on white surface
ret,imthresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,160, 255,type=cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Remove small breaks in lines
kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
imthresh=cv2.erode(imthresh,kernel, iterations=1)

# Setup SimpleBlobDetector parameters.
params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()

# Filter by Area.
params.filterByArea = True
params.minArea = 0
params.maxArea =350

# Don't filter by Circularity
params.filterByCircularity = False

# Don't filter by Convexity
params.filterByConvexity = False

# Don't filter by Inertia
params.filterByInertia = False


# Create a detector with the parameters
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)

# Detect blobs.
keypoints = detector.detect(imthresh)

# Draw detected blobs as red circles.
# cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS ensures
# the size of the circle corresponds to the size of blob
im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(imthresh, keypoints, np.array([]), (0,0,255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

# Show blobs
cv2.imshow("Keypoints", im_with_keypoints)

cv2.imshow('threshold',imthresh)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```